# iphone stroke path used for clipping UIImage

Tags: iphone, uiimage, cgcontext, cgpath, stroke

I'm very new to CoreGraphics (although I've been doing iphone programming for a while)

Question, I have this snippet that scales proportionally and clips an UIImage to a circle:

```
-(UIImage *)counterpartImageForSchedule:(Schedule *)counterpartSchedule inSize:(CGSize)size
{
    // This function returns a newImage, based on image, that has been:
    // - scaled to fit in (CGRect) rect
    // - and cropped within a circle of radius: rectWidth/2

    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"fakeuser1.png"];

    // when kendy sends hash, check that this image is not on the cache, otherwise download, clip & stylized
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height), NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


                //Get the width and heights
    CGFloat imageWidth = image.size.width;
    CGFloat imageHeight = image.size.height;
    CGFloat rectWidth = size.width;
    CGFloat rectHeight = size.height;

    //Calculate the scale factor
    CGFloat scaleFactorX = rectWidth/imageWidth;
    CGFloat scaleFactorY = rectHeight/imageHeight;

    if (scaleFactorX>scaleFactorY) {
        scaleFactorY=scaleFactorX;
    } else
    {
        scaleFactorX=scaleFactorY;
    }


    //Calculate the centre of the circle
    CGFloat imageCentreX = rectWidth/2;
    CGFloat imageCentreY = rectHeight/2;

    // Create and CLIP to a CIRCULAR Path
    // (This could be replaced with any closed path if you want a different shaped clip)
    CGFloat radius = rectWidth/2;
    CGContextBeginPath (context);
    CGContextAddArc (context, imageCentreX, imageCentreY, radius, 0, 2*M_PI, 0);


    CGContextClosePath (context);

    CGContextClip (context);

    //Set the SCALE factor for the graphics context
    //All future draw calls will be scaled by this factor
    CGContextScaleCTM (context, scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);    
    // the stroke

    // Draw the IMAGE
    CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    [image drawInRect:myRect];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();



    return newImage;
}
```

Question is, how can I stroke the path I'm using to clip the image (say, 4 pixels with black or white color)? do i need to draw a new one?

any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A path can be an object like any other - in this case, a CGPath (CGPathRef). Before using the path for anything, encapsulate it as a CGPath (in this case, probably a CGMutablePathRef, or perhaps you can call CGContextCopyPath before using the path to clip to). Now you can reuse that path.

Here's an example from one of my apps where I form a path, then stroke it, and then clip to the same path (`c` is the graphics context):

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(r) - radius, ins);
CGPathAddArc(path, nil, 
             radius+ins, radius+ins, radius, -M_PI/2.0, M_PI/2.0, true);
CGPathAddArc(path, nil, 
             CGRectGetMaxX(r) - radius, radius+ins, radius, M_PI/2.0, -M_PI/2.0, true);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
CGContextAddPath(c, path);
CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 2);
CGContextStrokePath(c);
CGContextAddPath(c, path);
CGContextClip(c);
CGPathRelease(path);
```

Another possibility is to use UIBezierPath - a full-fledged Objective-C object, instead of CGContext functions. It encapsulates a CGPath and you can reuse that path - clip to it, then stroke it. Or the other way round.

Comment: completely rookie at this matt, CGContextBeginPath (context); has a void return, how can I do what you suggest?

Comment: I don't understand what that has to do with it. Look at the documentation for CGMutablePathRef. Also see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_paths_and_drawing

Comment: And I edited my answer, sticking in some example code from one of my apps. Note how, having formed the path, I can add it and stroke it, then add it again and clip to it.

Comment: testing it, let me check and I'll accept the answer, appreciate your help matt!

Comment: Have fun! I really like Core Graphics and am glad to see you're getting into it. The ability to create a UIImage drawing in real time is a very cool part of iOS, and not enough people take advantage of it.

Comment: i know, been doing iOs since 99, just for this one project I need to take a square image, scale it, clip it to a circle and add a stroke. Still having issue implementing your solution but that's a rookie's fault. I just need to get this one done and move forward (lots of stuff to do in this project!!!!) so I'm not looking to be becoming a CoreGraphics guru overnight

Comment: Take time to look at UIBezierPath. Making a circle, stroking it, and clipping to it is _trivial_. You don't even need to supply a graphics context: it automatically uses the current context which you've already created.