# CIPerspectiveCorrection return image as is, not stretched

Tags: ios, swift, crop, cifilter

I'm using CIFilter's CIPerspectiveCorrection to crop an image, but the part I want to crop is not always a perfect rectangle so the cropped image returns distorted.

[image]

```
let filter: CIFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIPerspectiveCorrection")!
filter.setValue(CIImage(cgImage: inputImage.cgImage!), forKey: "inputImage")
filter.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint: topLeft), forKey: "inputTopLeft")
filter.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint: topRight), forKey: "inputTopRight")
filter.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint: bottomLeft), forKey: "inputBottomLeft")
filter.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint: bottomRight), forKey: "inputBottomRight")

let cutImageRef = CIContext(options: nil).createCGImage(filter.outputImage!, from: filter.outputImage!.extent)!

// Return image to UIImage
let croppedImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cutImageRef)
return croppedImage
```

How do I return the image as is on the 2d plane without stretching to fill a rectangle?

Comment: Do you just want a straight crop using the CICrop filter?

Comment: I just want the contents inside as I see it in the quadrilateral, shouldn't necessarily be in the shape of a rectangle.

Comment: "How do I return the image as is on the 2d plane without stretching to fill a rectangle?"  That's not what CIPerspectiveCorrection is for.

Comment: I've never used it, but try using CICrop instead.

Comment: It seems like CICrop only takes in a rectangle as a key.

Comment: i want to crop image like you are cropping right now which cropper are you using @jenny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just the inside of the polygon *as is*, you can use the Core Graphics APIs for masking the image with a path.
Maybe you can find some inspiration in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853122/swift-clipping-image-with-uibezierpath).