# Crop quadrilateral image from image to swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to crop a quadrilateral path from an image, I am using swiftUI. I have access to the coordinates of the four points that define the quadrilateral. I see that you can crop using CGRect however that does not work for me since it only works for rectangles and I need quadrilaterals. I have looked around and it seems people have done it by using UIImageView [Like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853122/swift-clipping-image-with-uibezierpath) but I am not sure where I can get a UIImageView and reconcile it with swiftUI to display it.

Comment: The post you linked to gives you a UIImage, which you can display in SwiftUI: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/init(uiimage:)

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction, it worked!